# Dockerised web application in production

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a web application dockerised with some containers (mariadb, PHP, phpmyadmin...)
The data of the database is shared between Host and docker mariadb container (files stored on the Host machine)
Can I use this structure for production or should I use it only for development?

Comment: Please edit your question and add enough details so that it can be answered with facts. As is, it will only bring opinion based answers. You should probably narrow the problem to a particular concern you have bringing this to production in you particular context. Meanwhile, for what it's worth, I have several applications with a bind mount running on production without any problems (like an awx installation, a nexus server....)

Comment: I think yes, because without mounting volumes data will be lost once container is deleted.